# Bmesh: how can I import custom vertex normals

Tags: python, blender

I have a question concerning BMesh and custom vertex normals editing.
At the moment I am writing a little blender importer for a custom data format and I am stuck with importing/manipulating custom normals. I am using the bmesh module because I want to use it's functionalities before transforming the bmesh into a real mesh.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to set the normals with bmesh? 
Do i need to import them with the Mesh module?

Thanks a lot in advance for any tipp!

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39764/935

Comment: thanks for your comment. This does not quite answer my question compleatly though.
From the answer to the posted thread:
    _Finally, you must be in Object mode currently, custom normals at BMesh level (Edit mode) are not yet supported really._ I would like to find a way to still use bmesh with custom normals...